# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSIndexPath]' with a type Int

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I'm currently converting a project to Swift 2 using Xcode 7 beta, and I am currently getting the error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSIndexPath]?' with a type 'Int'

for the following ling of code:

```
let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as! NSIndexPath
```

when trying to pass data to a view controller when a user selects a cell in the `UICollectionView` using `prepareForSegue` method.

Here is the complete `prepareForSegue` method. I am unsure if this is a Swift 2 error, but it works fine when using Swift 1.1 for iOS 8.4.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "details" {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController

    let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as! NSIndexPath

    let selectedItem = items[indexPath.row]

    vc.selectedItem = selectedItem

    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing `let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as! [NSIndexPath]`

Comment: @TheBeanstalk yeah this seemed to do the trick for now, still converting code and unable to run atm.   `let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as [NSIndexPath]!`

Comment: It might even work if you leave the `indexPaths` line alone, and instead do `let indexPath = indexPaths![0] as! NSIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS8 SDK, `indexPathsForSelectedItems` is declared as:

```
func indexPathsForSelectedItems() -> [AnyObject] // returns nil or an array of selected index paths
```

This was a bug in the SDK because `indexPathsForSelectedItems()` returns `nil` when there are no selected items.

In iOS9 SDK, that is declared as:

```
public func indexPathsForSelectedItems() -> [NSIndexPath]?
```

2 differences here

- The bug was fixed, and returns `Optional`
- returns an array of `NSIndexPath` instead of `AnyObject` since Objective-C supports simple Generics.

So,

- You have to unwrap it.
- You don't need to cast them to `NSIndexPath`

Try:

```
 let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
 let indexPath = indexPaths[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should unwrap array then use it so this code should work:

```
let indexPath = indexPaths?[0] as! NSIndexPath
```

By the way, avoid using ! to unwrap variables that have chance to be nil or your final app will face runtime crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap the array but instead of forcing the unwrap with ! it might be safer to use if let to make sure you are not unwrapping nil

```
if let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() where indexPaths.count > 0{
    let indexPath = indexPaths[0]
}
```